# Python script and mysql database with update query does't work

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, sql-update

I have a python script that I created to update a MySQL database the insert work perfect but when I tried to update it nothing happen and it doesn't change.

The console displays this error from the try and except

> Unable to print data

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

MySQL database

Database `student`

Table structure for table `stu`

```
Column  Type    Null    Default
ID  int(8)  No  
Name    varchar(255)    No  
subject varchar(255)    No
```

Dumping data for table `stu`

```
11  jhon    python
12  jina    hjsdhjsd
13  jaSDJ   JHAISDJ
```

Python script

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    # UPDATE AND delete some values from the database ###
    import MySQLdb

    db = MySQLdb.Connect("localhost", "****", "******", "student")

    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = "UPDATE  STU SET NAME = MAROUN, SUBJECT = C++ WHERE ID = 13 "

    try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
#     r = cursor.fetchall()
#     for row in r:
#         ID = row[0]
#         NAME = row[1]
#         SUBJECT = row[2]
# print "ID = %d, LAST_NAME = %s, SUBJECT = %s  " %(ID, NAME, SUBJECT)
    print "update ok "
except Exception as e:
    print e
db.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps `UPDATE  STU SET NAME ='MAROUN', SUBJECT = 'C++' WHERE ID = 13`

Comment: it did not work also neither it did not print the error witch mean it did not pass to the try except

Comment: To fix the error, you should know what exactly the error is. Instead of just 'except' add 'except Exception as e:' and inside that block print e

Comment: i will edit my post and add the sql table because now the script is good but nothing change on the database